# Android - How to check if GPS signal was lost

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to find how to check if GPS have still signal, how can I do it? I'm using:

```
locationManager.addGpsStatusListener(new MyGPSListener());

private class MyGPSListener implements GpsStatus.Listener
    {
        public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event)
        {
            switch (event) {
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_SATELLITE_STATUS:
                    if (mLastLocation != null) {
                        isGPSFix = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastLocationMillis) < 3000;
                    }

                    if (isGPSFix) { 
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(GPS_ENABLED).sendToTarget();
                    } else {
                        mHandler.obtainMessage(GPS_DISABLED).sendToTarget();
                    }

                    break;
                case GpsStatus.GPS_EVENT_FIRST_FIX:
                    isGPSFix = true;

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is not solution, the GPS signal was not lost here. This is just "when device is not moving for 3 sec = GPS LOST", but I want event to GPS was rly lost, cause I'm using this in my "car app"... So I need to know if I drove into the tunnel, for example.

I'm googling it for a long day and I don't have any solution. How does it work? Why does not it work? When android and another apps know it, then I want to know it too!

Thanks for answers.

EDIT:

I tried to combine this with the latest speed, but it's useless ... rate would have to be greater than 20 km / h.. and what if I go in the tunnel 1 km / h? It makes no sense...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
xml:
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

onCreate:
NetState receiver = new NetState();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
this.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
receiver.onReceive(this, null);

add class:
class NetState extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo gprs = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if(!gprs.isConnected() && !wifi.isConnected())
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            ab.setMessage("please check network");
            ab.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();

        }
        else{
            AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            ab.setMessage("Network connect succeed!");
            ab.setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }).show();               

        }
    }
}
```

I hope it is helpful to you ~

Comment: it's not helpful, that's detection of gprs & network connection - I need detect signal of GPS satelite